# Flask backend flash messages to display on react frontend

Tags: html, reactjs, flask, flash-message

Hi i have a flask app with a react front end. Where the react htmls generated through npm build are rendered. I also want the react frontend to show these flash messages as per the conditions. But since the backend and frontend are not dynamically connected. What options do i have to resolve this issues ? Below i have sample code showing some of the conditions.

```
@user.route('/supervised', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def supervised():
    form = SubmitData()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        try:
            file2 = request.files['file2']
        except werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError:
            file2 = None
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if allowed_file(file.filename) is False:
            flash('Please upload a .csv file for training dataset.')
            return redirect(request.url)
        flash('Message')
                return render_template('support.html')
    return render_template('supervised.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to generate response objects in Flask and display them in React (ex. with `fetch`).
As for your code, you can do it like this in Flask:

```py
@user.route('/supervised', methods=['POST'])
  def supervised():
      request_body = request.get_json()
      #Check Request body for file
      #example 
      filename = request_body["filename"]

      if filename == '':
       res = make_response(jsonify({'message': 'No file part'}), 200)
       return res

      res = make_response(jsonify({"message": "File received})"}), 200)
      return res
```

The React/JS part could look like this (I coded this one by feeling but for me it does the trick with given scheme)

```js
export default function Supervision() {

  const [Message, setMessage] = useState(null);

  function submit() {

       var fileInput = document.getElementById('upload');   
       var filename = fileInput.files[0].name;

        var entry = {
            filename: filename.value,
        };

        fetch("/supervised", {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: "include",
            body: JSON.stringify(entry),
            cache: "no-cache",
            headers: new Headers({
                "content-type": "application/json"
            })
          }).then((response)  => {
                   console.log(response)
                   console.log(response.status)
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    console.log("Response status was not 200.");
                    return;
                }
                return response.json();
              })
                .then((ResponseJSON) => {
                    console.log(ResponseJSON);
                    setMessage(ResponseJSON)
                });

        }
 useEffect(() => {
            submit();
 }, []);

  return (
   <form>
      <h3>TEST</h3>
      <br></br>
    <input type="file" id="upload" name="avatar" accept="image/png, 
     image/jpeg" />
    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={submit} type="button" >
         Submit
    </button>
    {Message && <div>
                    <p> {Message.message}</p>
                </div>
   }
   </form> 
  )
}
```